# jQuery get value of datetimepicker onchange

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I'm trying to make my input `scheduletime` react based on the current date picked on input `scheduledate`.

For Example:

if I choose 2019-10-13 in `scheduledate`
- my `onchange` function will `getDay()`
- the value of day will determine which will be assigned to `$timer` via `switch`.

In this one `getDay()` should give 0 as the day of the date is Sunday so $timer should get the value of '1,2,3'

I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control dp" id="scheduledate" name="scheduledate"/>

<input type="text" class="form-control tp" id="scheduletime" name="scheduletime"/>
```

the function for my `onchange` for `scheduledate`

```
 <script>
  $('#scheduledate').on('change',function() {
   var day =  $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
   switch(day.getDay())

     case 0:
         <?php $timer =  "1,2,3"; ?>
         break;
     case 1:
         <?php $timer = "4,5,6";  ?>
         break;
     case 2:
         <?php $timer = "7,8,9";  ?>
         break;
     case 3:
         <?php $timer = "10,11,12";  ?>
         break;
     case 4:
         <?php $timer = "13,14,15";  ?>
         break;
     case 5:
         <?php $timer = "16,17,18";  ?>
         break;
     case 6:
         <?php $timer = "19,20,21";  ?>
         break;

  });
 </script>
```

javascript for my `scheduledate` picker

```
 <script>
   $(".dp").datetimepicker({
         format: 'Y-M-D', minDate: new Date(),
         icons: {
             time: "fa fa-clock-o",
             date: "fa fa-calendar",
             up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
             down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
             previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
             next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
             today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
             clear: 'fa fa-trash',
             close: 'fa fa-remove'
         },

 })
 </script>
```

javascript for my `scheduletime` picker

```
 <script>
   $(".tp").datetimepicker({
         format: 'HH:mm', stepping: 15, enabledHours: [<?php echo $timer; ?>],
         icons: {
             time: "fa fa-clock-o",
             date: "fa fa-calendar",
             up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
             down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
             previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
             next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
             today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
             clear: 'fa fa-trash',
             close: 'fa fa-remove'
         }
 });  
 </script>
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: This code in your JS file will produce absolutely no output: ``<?php $timer =  "1,2,3"; ?>``. Perhaps you mean to create a global ``timer`` variable, and then say: ``timer = "1,2,3"``. And change this: ``format: 'HH:mm', stepping: 15, enabledHours: [<?php echo $timer; ?>]`` to ``format: 'HH:mm', stepping: 15, enabledHours: [ timer ]``

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```js
$('#scheduledate').on('change',function() {
   var day =  $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
   fetch(window.location.href, {
       method: 'POST',
       body: day.getDay()
   })//.then(() => {window.location.reload()}) <-- To reload page if needed.
```

and php:

```php
<?php 
$input = $_POST
switch($input) {
    case '0':
        $timer = '1, 2, 3'
    // Other cases...
}
?>
```